# How do I put pair values into missing values using SAS?

Tags: sas, missing-data

The data looks like: 
`ID     Year    A    B
1  1279  1996   0   0
2  1279  2003   0   1
3  1447  1993   1   0
4  1447  2001   1   1
5  1487  1967   0   0
6  1487  2008   1   .
7  1487  2008   1   .
8  1487  2009   0   1
9  1678  1979   1   0
10 1678  2002   1   1
11 1690  1989   1   0
12 1690  1993   0   .
13 1690  1993   0   .
14 1690  1996   0   .
15 1690  1996   0   .
16 1690  1997   0   1`

I created a variable B. The ID with the earliest year has a value of 0 for B, and the ID with the latest year has a value of 1 for B. However, all other ID get a second observation created, one observation has a value of 1 for B and the other has a value of 0 for B.

So the output would like: 
`ID           Year  A   B
 1  1279     1996   0   0
 2  1279     2003   0   1
 3  1447     1993   1   0
 4  1447     2001   1   1
 5  1487     1967   0   0
 6  1487     2008   1   1*
 7  1487     2008   1   0*
 8  1487     2009   0   1
 9  1678     1979   1   0
 10 1678     2002   1   1
 11 1690     1989   1   0
 12 1690     1993   0   1*
 13 1690     1993   0   0*
 14 1690     1996   0   1*
 15 1690     1996   0   0*
 16 1690     1997   0   1`

The B sequence should be 0 and 1. And I need to put 1 and 0 into the missing values. 
Could anyone help me here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your code to create the above we can't do a lot.

I'm assuming that you're using by values for these and sorting by id then year. If so this loop is tested and working:

```
data newdata;
    set data;
    by id year;
    if first.id then
    do;
        count=0;
        B=0;
    end;
    if not first.id and not last.id then
    do;
        count+1;
        B=mod(count,2);
    end;
    if last.id then
    B=1;
run;
```

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: My code is 
data newdata;
  set data;
  by ID;
  if First.ID then B = 0;
  else if Last.ID then B = 1;
run;

Next I am stuck here.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Just make sure you proc sort data by id year first.

Comment: It's exactly what I need to do. Thank you so much!! I really appreciate it.